# Nesting environment inside new command generating errors

Tags: macros, environments, nesting

Extreme TeX novice, sorry for the length of the example, I wasn't sure what packages were important to replicate the problems.  I was trying to create a simple command that I could use to injected labeled comments into an existing document.  My comment would be in text color blue and be prefixed with initials ('[XXX]' in this example)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm, bbm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm, bbm}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx, color, epsf}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{xr, zref, hyperref}
\usepackage{etoolbox, siunitx}
%
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\usepackage{scrextend}
%
\newcommand\xxx[1] {\newline\textcolor{blue}{[XXX] #1}}

\begin{document}
\title{A title}
\author{A person}
\maketitle
\section{A section}
Some section stuff
\xxx{a comment}
\begin{verbatim}
This is 
text that 
presented 'as-is'
\end{verbatim}
Some more text
\xxx{
abc
\begin{verbatim}
verbatim
\end{verbatim}
}
\end{document}
```

Generates:

```
line 37: Argument of \@xverbatim has an extra }. } 
line 37: Paragraph ended before \@xverbatim was complete. } 
line 37: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. } 
: Emergency stop. 
: Command \@footnotemark has changed.
```

I tried to define a newenvironment (not shown) used by the command, thinking that perhaps the 'command' couldn't handle nested content, but it didn't help.

1. I'd like to understand what I have done wrong and how I might figure out such issues in the future.
2. Find a concise summary of the TeX syntax (not LaTeX, just basic basic TeX).
3. Understand how to get rid of that footnotemark warning.  Is some package redefining that command?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Verbatim is complicated in all possible ways.  In general, a verbatim command or environment will not work in the argument of another command.

Comment: Are there alternatives to verbatim?

Comment: it depends, for your example you could just use `\texttt{verbatim}` to get that font but verbatim makes all the special characters non-special so `\frac` just prints \frac rather than making a fraction, that can not work in an argument.

Comment: With “verbatim” I mean the entire concept of printing “as-is”, not the specific environment. You can, for example, do `\newcommand\xxx{\begingroup\color{blue}[XXX]}` and `\newcommand\zzz{\endgroup}`, then write `\xxx` before the environment and `\zzz` after.  Or you can define `\newenvironment{blueverbatim}{\color{blue}[XXX]\verbatim}{\endverbatim}` and use `blueverbatim` instead

Comment: unrelated but you almost certainly don't want to load `epsf` (unless you are writing this document in the 1980s) also `\newline\textcolor` looks wrong you should rarely need `\newline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use xparse's `+v`-type-argument for having LaTeX read and tokenize everything in verbatim-category-code-régime and then passing things to `\scantokens` for re-tokenization, but if you do this, then `\xxx` cannot be used within macro-arguments/macro-definitions/etc:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
%
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\begingroup
\newcommand\xxx[1]{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\xxx{%
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\^^I=12 %
    \innerxxx
  }%
  \NewDocumentCommand{\innerxxx}{+v}{%
    \endgroup
    \textcolor{blue}{[XXX] %
    \begingroup
    \newlinechar=\endlinechar
    \scantokens{\endgroup##1#1}}%
  }%
}%
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\xxx{%}%

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A person}

\maketitle

\section{A section}

Some section stuff

\xxx{a comment}bla

\begin{verbatim}
This is 
text that 
presented 'as-is'
\end{verbatim}

Some more text

\xxx{%
abc
\begin{verbatim*}
verbatim
\end{verbatim*}
}%

Indenting is funny when nesting verbatim-environment in verbatim-argument:

\xxx{%
  abc
  \begin{verbatim*}
  verbatim
  \end{verbatim*}
}%

Indenting is funny when nesting verbatim-environment in verbatim-argument:

\xxx{%
  abc
  \begin{verbatim*}
  verbatim
    verbatim
\end{verbatim*}
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]